# Error from NPM on ASP.NET 5 on restoring packages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I'm restoring NPM packages on my ASP.NET 5 (vNext) project, I get following errors/warnings:

```
====Executing command 'npm install'====


npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No README data

====npm command completed with exit code 0====
```

Is this something I can fix, or is this an issue with ASP.NET 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just warnings and can be ignored.  If you would rather not see the warnings, you can add the missing properties to your package.json file:

```
{
    "description": "put description here",
    "repository": "repository info here",
    "readme": "readme data goes here"
}
```